# Android Studio App Won't Appear in App List (Intent and Unsupported String Error)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

This is my first Android App. I'm trying to get it to run on an emulator but first had an issue that mentioned how the example activity "needed to be called with intent" or something along those lines. 
Looking at the Developers API, I couldn't quite get a straight answer as to how to format an intent-filter.

Here is the code I have to get to the example activity:

```
            public void onClick(View view){
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExampleActivity.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }
```

How do I properly create the intent filter? Maybe this is correct?:

```
    <activity android:name=".ExampleActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Example.example"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

After attempting to create the intent filter, I ran into a problem with running the app, let alone, having the app appear in the app list. In the gradle console, I see errors such as "Error: unsupported type 'String'" in my tags.xml file. The error looks like this:

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<String name="art_tag">Art</String>
<String name="music_tag">Music</String>
<String name="food_drink_tag">Food and Drink</String>
<String name="sports_tag">Sports</String>
<String name="community_tag">Community</String>
<String name="health_fitness_tag">Health and Fitness</String>
<String name="family_tag">Family</String>
<String name="entertainment_tag">Entertainment</String>
<String name="technology_tag">Technology</String>
<String name="outdoors_tag">Outdoors</String>
<String name="gaming_tag">Gaming</String>
<String name="competition_tag">Competition</String>
<String name="networking_tag">Networking</String>
<String name="theatre_tag">Theatre</String>
<String name="culture_tag">Culture</String>
```

Merging result:ERROR

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\ExampleApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:13-26:29 Error:
    Missing one of the key attributes 'action#name,category#name' on element intent-filter at AndroidManifest.xml:24:13-26:29

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\WebblenEvents\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
:app:processDebugManifest (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.452 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.webblen.webblenevents">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Webblen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Webblen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".EventsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.webbblen.webblenevents"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you paste the xml code in tags.xml? it could be that you referencing a string resource that does not exist, kindly paste it!

Comment: yep, just added the file

Comment: XML is case-sensitive, try changing `String` to `string` (lowercase s)

Comment: Alright, so I lowercased the string tags and now I have a new error :/ There seems to be a problem with the manifest files? I

Comment: Try clean and rebuild solution, might fix the merger error!